# How much bytes is in Linux 1K, 1M or 1G

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is 1K in Linux 1024 bytes or 1000 bytes ? Or in other words is K one kilobyte (KB) or kibibyte (KiB)?

Does that factor hold for the other units as well like if it 1024 then
1M = 1024K and 1G = 1024M ?

Comment: What do you mean by “on Linux”? Output of `df`, `ls` and the likes? Linux is the kernel, it does not really deal with unit conversion.

Comment: [Why will Ubuntu no longer measure file size unit as byte, megabyte, gigabyte, etc?](https://askubuntu.com/q/465/253474), [Why do du -sh and the file manager disagree?](https://askubuntu.com/q/352597/253474)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which tools you're using and which APIs.

Historically it wasn't uncommon to use KB to mean 1024. While in fact the SI-Prefix Kilo indicates 1000. So you will find programs that use KB and mean KiB, you will find programs that use KB and mean KB.

This is further complicated if you have multiple tools interact with each other. You will have to evaluate it individually. There is no single truth for this.

Just as an example have a look at the [UnitsPolicy on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy).

Comment: [Ubuntu units manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/units.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
1024    KiB kibibyte    KB  kilobyte = 1 Mb
1024    MiB mebibyte    MB  megabyte = 1 Gb
1024    GiB gibibyte    GB  gigabyte = 1 Tb.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: And it is the marketing people who think 1000 bytes = 1kb.